# Order entries by custom date field

Tags: datetime, ordering, craft2

I want to modify this query so that the dated entries are sorted in descending order on a custom field called 'startDate'.

Have tried adding `.order('startDate')` to the end of the `craft.entries(query)...` but this causes any entry with a startDate to be excluded from the query.

(Maybe it's possible to set the order on just the `{% for entry in programmeEntriesDated...` loop?)

```
{% set query = { section: 'programme' } %}
{% set query = category is defined ? query | merge({ relatedTo: category }) : query %}
{% set programmeEntriesDated = craft.entries(query) %}

{# Show programme entries if available #}
{% if programmeEntriesDated|length %}
<div class="flex flex-wrap flex-row-ns">
  {# DATED ENTRIES #}
  {% for entry in programmeEntriesDated if (
        (entry.startDate|date('Y-m-d') >= now|date('Y-m-d'))
    or  (entry.endDate is not null and entry.endDate|date('Y-m-d') >= now|date('Y-m-d'))
    ) and
        (entry.type != 'old_programme_entry')
    and (entry.isOngoing == 0)
  %}
    {% include "_blocks/event_single.html" with { 'blockWidth' : 'w-100 w-third-ns' } %}
  {% endfor %}

  {# ONGOING ENTRIES  #}
  {% for entry in programmeEntriesDated if (entry.isOngoing) and
        (entry.type != 'old_programme_entry')
  %}
    {% include "_blocks/event_single.html" with { 'blockWidth' : 'w-100 w-third-ns' } %}
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: Your use of the order parameter is totally correct. Entries without a value in that field won't be excluded, they'll just appear last. Your first loop won't show them because of the condition (which is a bit strange because you are comparing strings with each other. That may cause unexpected behavior. I would suggest to compare the DateTime)

Comment: Ahh, I don't have a good grasp of how dates work in Twig, thanks for pointing that out Robin.

I just realised a hacky solution, I can reverse the first for loop with `for entry in programmeEntriesDated|reverse `

EDIT: Not really a true solution, as the events still aren't correctly sorted by date)

Comment: Or just re-order them correctly from the beginning with `ASC` or `DESC` you can compare Date objects directly with `entry.date >= now` PHP will compare the timestamps in your DateTime objects which is more accurate than strings

Comment: I can do that inside the original query?

Comment: Can't use entry.date because I want to search on the custom startDate field not the post date (I think...)

Comment: Then use `entry.startDate`.. It was just an example since there is no `date` property for an entry. And yes you have the full power of sql in your order by. You can even include `if` conditions in it https://stackoverflow.com/a/11003441/5604055 `order('IFNULL(content.field_startDate, entries.dateCreated')` or whatever you want (again - just an example to demonstrate your possibilities)